# Micronaut Custom Validator Not firing

Tags: groovy, bean-validation, micronaut

I am having trouble getting my custom validator to fire on my object.  The built-in constraints appear to work (Size for example) but myy `@UniqueUsername` does not seem to fire.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidator
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidatorContext
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import jakarta.inject.Singleton
import jakarta.validation.Constraint
import jakarta.validation.Payload

import java.lang.annotation.Documented
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Documented
@Target([ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER])
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
@interface UniqueUsername {
    String message() default "Username is already taken."
    Class<?>[] groups() default [ ]
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default []
}

@Singleton
@CompileStatic
class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {
    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository

    @Override
    boolean isValid(@Nullable String value, @NonNull AnnotationValue<UniqueUsername> annotationMetadata, @NonNull ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (userRepository.countByUsername(value) > 0) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.*
import io.micronaut.security.annotation.Secured
import io.micronaut.security.rules.SecurityRule
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
import io.micronaut.views.View
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolationException
import jakarta.validation.Valid
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size

@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
@Controller('/register')
@CompileStatic
class RegisterController {

    final UserRepository userRepository
    final RegisterService registerService

    RegisterController(UserRepository userRepository, RegisterService registerService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository
        this.registerService = registerService
    }

    @View('auth/register')
    @Get
    Map<String, Object> registration() {
        return Collections.emptyMap()
    }

    @View('auth/register')
    @Error(exception = ConstraintViolationException)
    Map<String, Object> constraintViolation(HttpRequest request, ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return ['errors': true] as Map<String, Object>
    }

    @Post
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    HttpResponse registerUser(@Valid @Body RegistrationForm registrationForm) {

        registerService.register(registrationForm.email, registrationForm.username, registrationForm.password)
        HttpResponse.ok()
    }
}

@Serdeable
@PasswordsMatch
class RegistrationForm {
    @Email
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    String email

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Size(max=50)
    @UniqueUsername
    String username

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    String password

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    String confirmPassword

    boolean doPasswordsMatch() {
        return password == confirmPassword
    }
}
```

## EDIT

I Tried changing to use `@Factory` like suggested but this also doesn't seem to work for me.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidator
import jakarta.inject.Inject
import jakarta.inject.Singleton

@Slf4j
@Factory
class ConstraintValidatorFactory {

    @Inject
    UserRepository userRepository

    @Singleton
    ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> uniqueUsernameValidator() {
        log.info("uniqueUsernameValidator called")
        return (value, annotationMetadata, context) -> {
            value && !userRepository.countByUsername(value)
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    ConstraintValidator<PasswordsMatch, RegistrationForm> passwordsMatchValidator() {
        return (value, annotationMetadata, context) -> (value.password == value.confirmPassword)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to implement your custom validators inside a factory as described here (that's the way I do this as well): https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-custom-validation-annotation-gradle-java.html

Comment: @RoarS. I must be missing something... Tried changing it to a Factory and still not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing from my build.gralde file

`implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")`

ONce I added that, my constraint started working.